# Web.Api help information for IHttpActionResult and an object

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using web.api and the help to display the interface for the end user.

The method I have is as follows:

```
public IHttpActionResult Initialize([FromBody]Initialize initalize)
    {   
       return Ok(Initialize(initalize));
    }
```

The Initialize returns back an InitializeOutput object.

I'd like to get the documentation to display the InitializeOutput in the help

Currently I am getting:

> Response Information
>
> Resource Description
>
> IHttpActionResult None.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As part of the Post-Build event command line you need to copy the XML file to the main WebAPI folder, ensuring that the names are different, e.g.

```
copy "$(SolutionDir)Business\App_Data\XmlDocumentBusiness.xml" "$(SolutionDir)\WebApi\App_Data\XmlDocumentBusiness.xml"
```